# I can change the values even when I use const word with my own array class template

Tags: c++, templates, constants

So I'm trying to write my own array template and everything works until i try to create a const object of my class template. in main.cpp I create the object with the copy contructor and I change it which I would expect to not work but it works. Help would be appreciated :D

**main.cpp**

```
# include "Array.hpp"

int main( void ) {

    Array<int> l = 1;
    l.setValue(5, 0);


    const Array<int> abc(l);
    std::cout << abc[0] << std::endl;
    abc[0] = 3;
    std::cout << abc[0] << std::endl;

    return (0);
}
```

**Array.tpp**

```
#ifndef ARRAY_TPP
# define ARRAY_TPP

# include "Array.hpp"

template<class T>
class Array {
private:

    int size_;
    T *array_;

public:
    Array() : size_(0), array_(new T[size_]) {};

    Array(int n) : size_(n), array_(new T[size_]) {};

    Array(Array const& src) : size_(src.size()), array_(new T[src.size()]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < src.size(); ++i) {
            array_[i] = src[i];
        }
    };


    Array& operator=(Array const& copy) {
        size_ = copy.size();
        delete[] array_;
        array_ = new T[size_];
        for (int i = 0; i < size_; i++)
            array_[i] = copy[i];
        return (*this);
    }

    T& operator[](int n) const {
        if (n < 0 || n >= size_)
            throw std::out_of_range("out of range");
        return (array_[n]);
    }


    int size(void) const { return (size_); };

    void setValue(T value, int n) {
        if (n < 0 || n >= size_)
            throw std::out_of_range("out of range");
        array_[n] = value;
    }

    ~Array() { delete[] array_; };
};

#endif
```

Comment: You return a non-`const` modifiable reference `T&` from method `operator[]`, which you marked as `const`.

Comment: btw I would not implement bounds checking in `operator[]`, but rather provide a bounds checked alternative `at`. If you use your `operator[]` in a loop: `for (int i=0;i < array.size(); ++i) { std::cout << array[i]; }` the bounds checking is totally superfluous but done anyhow in every iteration

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is this:

> ```
> T& operator[](int n) const {
>     if (n < 0 || n >= size_)
>         throw std::out_of_range("out of range");
>     return (array_[n]);
> }
> ```

Because this is declared to be a `const` method, it can be called on a `const Array`. Though, it returns a non-const reference to the element. Because `Array` stores the elements via a `T *`, only that pointer is `const` in a `const Array` while modifiying the elements via that pointer is "fine".

You need two overloads of `operator[]`:

```
 T& operator[](int n);
 const T& operator[](int n) const;
```

Comment: Also, the `const` version should return `const T&`.